# Is it possible to clean a Linux VPS using the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, centos, vps

Sometimes my friend give me root access to his [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) to help him install some programs and he leaves. Sometimes I mess with it, but I don't have the login information for [Parallels Virtuozzo Containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels,_Inc.#Server_software), so can I clean the VPS using SSH?

It's faster than formatting the VPS and re-installing the OS.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "clean up"?

Comment: @JJ everything but the OS and its default packages

Comment: everything we would install - in order to become just like a freshly installed centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always take a backup before you being work and revert the changes after the face. `rsync` is one potential tool you could use to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use that, since I'll never find a shell commend to clean the vps - I knew that I could back up my vps, but I was searching for a faster way, i guess there's no faster way :D

Comment: Once you make changes there is no "reset the OS" command. You either have to know what you changed and undo each change manually or restore from a backup.

Comment: yes that was my question, I'm not gonna undo everything manually coz sometimes i forgot what i did, and there's no reset command, and uninstalling and reinstalling the OS is time consuming